# You are standing into danger

Tags: phrases, terminology

On lists of nautical flag meanings ([one](http://www.sailorschoice.com/seamanship/alphabet_pennants.htm) and [another](http://www.maineharbors.com/flag.htm)), the letter U means *you are standing into danger*. I am familiar with the phrase from a sailing point of view - it means something like "if you keep doing what you're doing, something bad will happen." Like if you're headed for a reef or something. Today I used it (in a gentle, teasing tone) to a family member who was annoying me. And they asked "why *standing* and not *heading into danger*?"

I think it's because it also applies if you stay still; it just means whatever you are about to encounter will not be good. But I'd appreciate a little background on the history and etymology of the phrase, and whether it applies only if you're moving, or not moving, or whatever.

Comment: *You are standing **into** danger* is very non-standard English. You could just about get away with just replacing *into* with *in*, but most people would also discard the word *standing*.

Comment: exactly. you're standing in or heading into danger, right? But that's the phrase and I wonder why that's the phrase

Comment: From the OED: _stand_ v. 36.a. Naut. Of a vessel (hence of the commander, sailors, etc.): To sail, steer, direct one's course (in a specified direction, to sea, into harbour, etc.). Last citation 1705.

Comment: oic - well, it looks like it's just a minimal change from [flag signal NF](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8A1fIiO2xs8C&pg=PR15&dq=%22You+are+running+into+danger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3d_lUMyGBKSR0QW-noGgAw&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22You%20are%20running%20into%20danger%22&f=false), which means *You are **running** into danger*. That minimal change clarifies that **U** means you're in danger *right now* if you don't move, whereas with **NF** you'd be okay if you could just stay exactly where you are and *not move at all*.

Comment: ...belay that, since John obviously knew better. But I'll leave it there for the link.

Comment: Standing into danger. I've heard this used to mean, "If you stay where you are - you're in trouble soon". This was used as a signal to tell stopped warships, etc, that the enemy was approaching and, unless they moved away, they were a sitting duck. I've heard it more recently used when a colleague warned another that an opinion she held was becoming regarded as unacceptable prejudice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Stand* may mean ["hold a course at sea"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stand) or, more generally, ["face into"](http://www.takeourword.com/TOW176/page4.html).  Hence we have expressions such as "standing into the storm", which were likely broadened over time to contemplate non-nautical dangers.

I read "standing into" as implying movement most of the time, though I suppose it's not necessary: the world moves relative to us at times, just as one may stand on a ship's deck and be moved through the heart of a storm.  I think it seems all right to read the expression at issue as either "heading into danger" or "facing danger", but maybe someone with an open copy of the OED will weigh in.

Answer (score 2):

According to definition 12 at [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stand), "stand" can mean "To take or hold a particular course or direction", so "standing into danger" is equivalent to "sailing into danger".

Comment: Also see http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stand : [no object, with adverbial of direction] (of a ship) remain on a specified course: the ship was standing north

Answer (score 0):

That usage of standing is surely close to the same meaning as 'being brought up all standing' - which means to come to a halt abruptly without shortening sail - by going aground or hitting some obstacle.

the U flag infers that by going on in the same way the vessel will encounter some danger as yet unspecified and should alter course or let fly sheets - though it is only polite to follow the U signal with some further instruction or explanation.